# Local maximum vs global maximum in greedy algorithms

Tags: algorithm

In our algorithms class, the professor said that if while implementing a greedy algorithm we stuck in local maximum and thus assume that no more improvement is possible, then it might result in unsuccessful implementation. Can somebody give an example of when this can happen?

Comment: example of what? stucking in local maximum?

Comment: @JohnnyAW  Yes, stucking in local maximum and giving wrong answer as a result.

Answer (score 2):

imagine you need to find maximum number in an array, that has cohesive values(something like landscape, difference between near fields can't be higher than 1). You don't want to check all values for performance reasons you could try a simple greedy algorithm like: check a near-values, if its higher, go in this direction, if its lower go to another direction:

```
public static void findHighestValue(int[] landscape){
    boolean leftChecked = false;
    boolean rightChecked = false;
    // we start in the middle of that array
    int currentIndex = landscape.length / 2;
    // do work until both directions are checked
    while(!leftChecked || !rightChecked){
        //check left boundary
        if(currentIndex == 0)
            leftChecked = true;
        //check right bound
        if(currentIndex == landscape.length - 1)
            rightChecked = true;
        //first check if left value is equal or higher then current value
        if(!leftChecked){
            if(landscape[currentIndex - 1] >= landscape[currentIndex]){
                currentIndex--;
            } else {
                leftChecked = true;
            }
        } else if(!rightChecked) {
            //same for right side
            if(landscape[currentIndex + 1] >= landscape[currentIndex]){
                currentIndex++;
            } else {
                leftChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //print the result
    System.out.println("local maximum at index: " + currentIndex);
}
```

now try to call that mehtod with values like: {1,1,2,3,4,5,4,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5}. Depending on the start-point of the algorithm, it will find 5 as local-maximum or 7 as global maximum

as you can see this algorithm will go to a local maxmum and won't be able to leave it

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what do you mean by cohesive values?

Comment: it means, that the values relate to neighbour values, like a landscape, its not likely, that if you have a value 1, that your next value can be 9, in a landscape the value would more likely be 2. ill put an array example in the answer

Comment: But why would we use this strategy to find the maximum element. For example, lets say my array is 5 4 3 2 3 4 4 4 4, it will start with the element 3 and notice that it should go to the right and from that on it will just keep going to right and declare that 4 is the maximum element when in fact its 5.

Comment: sometimes you can't use an algorithm, that will give you a right answer in every possible scenario, because it would take ages to compute the right answer. In this case you just use a heuristic algorithm, that will calculate a "good" answer (it might be the best answer, but there is no guarantee for that). A greedy algorithm is a heuristic algorithm, that try to calculate a "good" answer in a short amount of time. You need to balance calculation time and how "good" is the answer

Comment: @s_123 imagine airline company, that want to calculate most profitable routes to 100 of airports with 100 of planes, with 1000 of pilots and stuff, they simply can't calculate the whole thing at once, since the problem has exponential growth and they would need moths or maybe years to calculate the best answer. Instead of doing it, they just use a heuritsic algorithm, that will give them a "good" answer

Comment: But won't this algorithm is good only when there is a high chance of sequences in strictly increasing or decreasing order because here we don't bother to check the left part of the array just because the element left to the middle element is less than the middle element and same for the right part.

Comment: I get that we sometimes need a "good" answer rather than the best one but how can we be sure that this algorithm gives even a "good" answer considering the fact the the elements of the array may not be a monotonic sequence pattern?

Comment: @s_123 yes, thats why I said, the values should be related to neighbours. Of course, this algorithm is quite dumb, but its a good way to show stucking in a local maximum. Another more complex heuristics may be more intelligent, but at the end, they stuck somewhere just like this one, or they might finish execution, after the next best solution don't provide good improvement on the solution value(e.g. < 1%)